# infinispan cache.put() throws null pointer exception even when values put are not null

Tags: caching, infinispan

trying to add content to infinispan cache and I get null pointer exception when i use the put method. Mine is a JSF web application. We are trying to achieve session replication using wildfly 13.

```
import org.infinispan.Cache;
public class index extends AbstractPageBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/web/web_repl")  
    Cache<String, String> ilsCache;  
    public Cache<String, String> getCache() {
        return ilsCache;
    }

    public void prerender() {
        ilsCache.put("Message", "Hello");
        logger.info("CACHE " + getCache());
    }
```

Log file

```
2018-08-21 14:21:57,134 ERROR [biz.autoscan.ils.index] (default task-1) index.java::Exception occured  : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at biz.autoscan.ils.index.btnLogin_action(index.java:930)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea why I still get null pointer exception fro cache.put()?

Edit: We are using WildFly 13 in domain mode and Infinispan in replication mode. My aim is to store the session object in the infinispan cache and share it between all the nodes.

Infinispan subsystem in domain.xml: This is how I have configured infinispan. We are using only two servers at the moment hence we have gone with replication mode.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:6.0">
    <cache-container name="web" aliases="ilsee" default-cache="web_repl" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
        <transport channel="ee" lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="Username"/>
        <replicated-cache name="web_repl">
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </replicated-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="dist">
            <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
            <file-store/>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: What makes you think cache.put is throwing null? Null in the exception above comes from your own code, which is incomplete here...

Comment: I realised that the error is with the initialization of the cache variable and it has nothing to do with the put method. The cache variable doesn't initialize. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you configure your server.

I will provide a generic example.
First, you need to configure your standalone.xml file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:core:9.2">
 <cache-container module="org.infinispan.extension:ispn-9.2" name="infinispan_container" default-cache="default">
   <transport/>
   <global-state/>
   <distributed-cache name="default"/>
   <distributed-cache name="myCache"/>
 </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

Then in your Java application, you need to inject the resource using

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datagrid-infinispan/container/infinispan_container/cache/myCache")
Cache cache;
```

As you can see **infinispan_container** and **myCache** are values that you provided in the XML configuration file.

There are two possible ways for your application to utilize Infinispan within Wildfly: embedded mode and server mode.
You can find more information http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#usage_3

Comment: Thank  you for the quick reply.   This name (@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/web/web_repl"))  works for me ie, it finds it but the cache doesn't get initialised. getCache() returns null. I have also edited my question by adding my infinispan configuration from the domain.xml

Comment: Your cache container is "web" and your cache is "web_repl". Your resource name should be "java:jboss/datagrid-infinispan/container/web/cache/web_repl"

Comment: I am using the infinispan distribution 6.0 for which jndi name is not a valid attribute. So I have configured the cache with the help of 
GlobalConfigurationBuilder. This way I am able to initialize cache and also add key value content to it but the problem is i cannot retrieve 
that content when I run another instance of the application. Is it because everytime I launch the application a new empty cache is 
created? If so then how do I check everytime the application is lauched whether cache is already created and retrieve the same instance of it?

Comment: GlobalConfigurationBuilder global = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC);
DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(global.defaultCacheName("web").build(), builder.build());
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache();
cache.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), cacheManager.getNodeAddress());
cache.put("Message2", "Good Morning");
cache.put("Message" , "Hello World");
cache.put("Session", session);

Comment: Any chance to update to the latest Final version? Here is an example of a cluster application https://github.com/diegolovison/infinispan-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/diegolovison/example/infinispan/ClusteredCacheManagerExample.java You need to run it twice. What is your OS ?

Comment: Thank you @Diego for your suggestions. I finally got cache container and cache to initialize using InitialContext like so CacheContainer container = InitialContext.doLookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/web"); 
Cache<String, String> cache = container.getCache("web_repl");

Comment: Could you please try @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/web") Cache cache;

Comment: I tried that before I came across InitialContext but it wouldn't initialize. Container was always null, but when I created a new small, simple web application and used @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/web") Cache cache; cache initialized and I was able to use it there. This is the part that i don't understand. Why my actual application works only with InitializeContext. This is the link i referred to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference under the sub-heading Standard Java SE JNDI API