# Why can't I get caches I added in wildfly config?

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan

I have 2 wildfly 13 standalone in cluster and an EE app deployed to both nodes.

I have a cacheable entity (@Cache from hibernate and @Cacheable from jpa) and it also has a named query using cache as well.

I want the named query cache to undergo invalidation when the entity is updated.

When I run the app, the provided cache named "entity" is working as expected: it does invalidate clusterwide when the entity is updated (it is of type invalidation_sync according to jmx).

The problem is with my custom cache: it is not started at deployment time, and when it is started, it is a local cache. No invalidation happens when the entity is updated.

I tried to lookup my custom cache using a @Startup ejb with no luck (cache not found) or, surprisingly, I get a NoClassDefFoundError on org.infinispan.Cache.

Suggestions from https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276133 and https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277425?start=15&tstart=0 does not help.

The custom cache I added in wildfly config is not started: I can't see it in jmx and I can't get it using the jndi lookup suggested by Paul Ferraro [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/981565#981565) following the jndi name pattern.

Here is the relevant portion of the entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter", schema = "public")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findByValue", query = "select p from Parameter p where p.valeur = :valeur", hints = {
                @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.CACHEABLE, value = "true"),
                @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.CACHE_REGION, value = "invalidation-query"),
                @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.CACHE_MODE, value = "NORMAL"),
                @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.COMMENT, value = "Parameter.findByValue")
        })
})
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "entity")
```

Here is the hibernate cache container portion of my standalone-full-ha.xml:

```xml
<cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
    <transport channel="omega-ee" lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <local-cache name="local-query">
        <object-memory size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <invalidation-cache name="entity">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <object-memory size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </invalidation-cache>
    <invalidation-cache name="invalidation-query">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <object-memory size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
    </invalidation-cache>
    <replicated-cache name="RPL-getParamGenTest" statistics-enabled="true">
        <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
    </replicated-cache>
    <replicated-cache name="replicated-entity" statistics-enabled="true">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

persistence.xml is as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/myDatasource</jta-data-source>

        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The code used to try the jndi lookup is like that:

```java
@Resource(name = "infinispan/replicated-query")
private Cache<?, ?> cache;
```

What am I missing?

I'm using wildfly 13, hibernate 5.1.14 and infinispan 9.2.4.

Comment: Hi, could you please double check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944012/infinispan-cache-put-throws-null-pointer-exception-even-when-values-put-are-no/51958037#51958037 and see if it helps ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck either. None of the jndi lookup gives a cache (using @Resource lookup). Checking the jndi view in the runtime of wildfly 's console shows only java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate (and others containers) and java:jboss/infinispan/configuration/hibernate/. In the later, there are configurations for entity and local-query caches, but mine is not there. Any ideas?
Can it be related to the fact I have to embed org.infinispan:core in my app to avoid the NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: You should try not to add your caches to the Hibernate cache container. Maybe add it to your own container cache container and see if that works? Alternatively, I'd suggest that you separate Hibernate caches from your own. For your own, you could deploy your own Infinispan library along with your deployment and manage the lifecycle/clustering...etc. This would allow you to use whichever Infinispan version you want for your own cache and let WildFly have control over Hibernate caches.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Infinispan 9.4 and try the following:

```xml
 <cache-container module="org.infinispan.extension:ispn-9.4" name="infinispan_container" default-cache="default">
   <transport/>
   <global-state/>
   <distributed-cache name="default"/>
   <distributed-cache name="memcachedCache"/>
   <distributed-cache name="namedCache"/>
 </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

```java
public class ExampleApplication {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datagrid-infinispan/container/infinispan_container")
    CacheContainer container;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datagrid-infinispan/container/infinispan_container/cache/namedCache")
    Cache cache;
}
```

See: http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#accessing_containers_and_caches

Comment: I'm having a hard time setting my standalone-full-ha.xml with the new subsystem your link indicates because i already have a jgroups subsystem but with a different xmlns and i feel they are incompatibles: wildfly won't start if i use jgroups:ispn-9.4.
I also feel confused between the wildfly I will use for production and the one started by infinispan in server mode (it is based on wildfly). I find the doc confusing on this. See the xmlns differs from subsystem in wildfly and in infinispan server mode.